# ASP.Net - MVC and Moq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, moq

I'm starting to build up Unit Tests for a project we have. We've decided upon Moq to assist with the 'Mocking' of the repositorys as we dont want to run the tests against the live DB.

I'm obviously using Moq incorrectly, How would one write the GetMessage Test? The first 2 seem to work fine.

The return value of the GetMessage Test is allways null so the test fails

```
private Mock<IMessageRepository> _mockRepository;
        private IMessageBoardService _service;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _mockRepository = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
            _service = new MessageBoardService(_mockRepository.Object);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateMessage()
        {
            var result = _service.CreateMessage("Test", "Description", 8000, 0);
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CreateComment()
        {
            var Message = _service.CreateMessage("Test", "Description", 8000, 0);
            var Result = _service.CreateComment("Test Comment", Message.MessageID, 0);
            Assert.IsNotNull(Result);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetMessage()
        {
            var Message = _service.CreateMessage("Test", "Description", 8000, 0);
            _service.AddMessage(Message);
            _service.Save();

            var RetMessage = _service.GetMessage(Message.MessageID); //Always returns Null

            Assert.IsNotNull(RetMessage);
        }
```

EDIT= == ===============================

What about the following?

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetMessage()
        {
            var tmpMessage = _service.CreateMessage("Test", "Description", 5, 0);
            _mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetMessage(It.IsAny<int>()))
                    .Returns(tmpMessage);

            var RetMessage = _service.GetMessage(tmpMessage.MessageID);

            Assert.IsNotNull(RetMessage);
        }
```

Comment: What is your current problem with the GetMessage test? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: I have updated the post. The return value is allways null so the test fails

Comment: But what do you expect instead? Is the GetMessaage method querying the Repository? What does the IMessageRepository interface look like?

Comment: Updated with another code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to setup the Stub so that you verify that the correct message ID is being passed to the repository's method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetMessage()
{
    var tmpMessage = _service.CreateMessage("Test", "Description", 5, 0);
    _mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetMessage(tmpMessage.MessageID))
        .Returns(tmpMessage);

    var RetMessage = _service.GetMessage(tmpMessage.MessageID);

    Assert.AreEqual(tmpMessage, RetMessage);
}
```

Notice that I have also modified the assertion so that it verifies what you are likely to care about: that the returned value is correct (and not just whether it's null or not).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just needed pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an expectation for you mock. Something like:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _mockRepository = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
        _mockRepository.Setup(r=> r.GetMessage())
                       .Returns(8000); // I assume 8000 is message Id in test
        _service = new MessageBoardService(_mockRepository.Object);
    }
```

I have assumed that your repository has a GetMessage that the Service uses. It is the method that the service uses that needs to be mocked.

This will be done for all uses of this mock. For that reason I would set it up in the individual test rather than initialize. I just wanted to highlight you need an expectation.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Thanks Daniel, 8000 was just a random ID, since this is attached to no database. Can you explain what exactly it is you have done here?

Comment: The Expect method is Obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: Another problem with this answer is that it sets up the mock in the Initialize method, which hard-codes the mock to return 8000 in all tests.

Comment: @Mark, can you post what you would do? I assume I am to use .Setup rather than .Expect - _mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetMessage(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Message());